# Call prerequisites multiple times during execution

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I'm using Make for handling basic tasks in a project, and I have the following signature in my `Makefile`:

```
.PHONY: exec lint test

exec:
    docker-compose exec service ${CMD}

lint: CMD := npm run lint
lint: exec

test: CMD := npm run test
test: exec
```

When I run the `make lint test` command I want it to run both `npm run lint` and `npm run test` inside the Docker container.

But as I observed it doesn't happen because `make` consider the prerequisite to be done after the `lint` task run and I get

> make: Nothing to be done for 'test'.

message upon calling it. This is totally understandable from make's point of view, but it's a side-effect for my usage.

**Is there a way to solve this inside the Makefile, without creating a shell script to act as an intermediate agent?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After getting inspiration from @madscientist and digging into the documentation I found what I was looking for: [Canned Recipes](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Canned-Recipes) allow to declare a list of commands to be reused in multiple tasks (recipes).

The following will satisfy the example from the question:

```
.PHONY: exec

define exec =
    docker-compose exec service ${CMD}
endef

lint: CMD := npm run lint
lint:
    $(exec)

test: CMD := npm run test
test:
    $(exec)
```

While the solution from @madscientist can also work, I feel this is superior because it doesn't cause recursive `make` call and a task is not splitted into two pieces (assigning the CMD variable and calling the `exec` task)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to get `make` to build the same target multiple times within a single invocation of make.  That's just not how it works: it builds a thing, then expects it to be up to date for the rest of that session.

You can use recursive invocations of make to do what you want:

```
.PHONY: lint test exec

lint: CMD := npm run lint
test: CMD := npm run test

lint test:
        $(MAKE) exec CMD=$(CMD)

exec:
        docker-compose exec service ${CMD}
```